# moodle XML to html

Tags: xml, moodle

I find it limiting to view/manage moodle XML question bank files in moodle alone, as there seems to be no way to view the questions/solutions (with their hierarchical structure) in one document.
Is it possible to convert the moodle XML file into e.g. one HTML page ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [HTML preview](https://moodle.org/plugins/qformat_htmltable) question export format? It sounds pretty close to what you are requesting

Comment: Thanks, that is useful but seems to do only one question at a time ? I want/need to see all questions at once in a "big" html page.

Comment: Question format can be used to export multiple questions. Try installing the module and you will find the new export option in questions export. For more info on how to export questions see https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Export_questions

Comment: You may also want to check the http://www.moodle2word.net/ site. Word format can be converted to html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, VERY helpful. However, "This plugin requires installation of the XSL PHP extension", and I have no admin rights or other extensive system priviliges.

Comment: Are you sure xsl is not already installed? Are you getting any errors during plugin installation?